# Quadratic Minimization Problem with positivity constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Let $A \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $b,c\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the following minimization problem:
$$
\min_{x\succeq 0} f(x):= \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-c\|^2 +  b^\top Ax.
$$
For the unconstrained case $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, Since the function is quadratic, and in case $A^\top A$ is invertible, the solution is found by imposing
$$
\nabla_x f(x) = 0 \iff x^\star = (A^\top A)^{-1}(A^\top c -  A^\top b).
$$
If we add the constraint $x\succeq 0$, is $x^\star_{+} = \max\{0,x^\star\}$ a solution? ($\max$ is the element-wise maximum operator here).

**Related question: [Simple Quadratic Minimization Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472560/simple-quadratic-minimization-problem)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. As an example, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}, \quad b = 0, \quad c = \pmatrix{1\\-1}.
$$
The solution to the unconstrained problem is $x^\star = (1,-1)$, but the constrained problem has solution $x = (1/5,0)$.

Comment: If $n = m =1$ is that true?

Comment: @Apprentice Yes. But all that says is that for a quadratic function $f$, if the true minimum is a negative number, then the constrained solution is $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, I thought that this simple case could be generalized to more dimensions, but as you pointed out that's not the case.